# Printing omission in Mumford's "Lectures on Curves on an Algebraic Surface"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

On page 174 of both copies I can access of Mumford's book "Lectures on Curves on an Algebraic Surface" there is a printing omission (like [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215487/definition-of-strongly-stable-0-cycle)).

> LEMMA 2: Let $A$ be a complete $p$-adic ring where $p$ is not a zero-divisor, such that $A/p$ is perfect. Then there is a 1-1 correspondence between members of $A$ and sequences $(\xi_0,\xi_1,\ldots)$ of elements of $A/p$, given by...

Who can supply the missing text?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Russian edition it is $$(\xi_0,\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots)\leftrightarrow f(\xi_0)+pf(\xi_1)+p^2f(\xi_2)+\dots$$ where $f$ is the Teichmuller map.